# Double account section on the active section of the profile of per-site meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, per-site-meta

I found a weird bug: The account section shows up twice on  he active section of the the profile page of a per-site meta. I checked three sites: Math (graduated), Puzzling (public beta), and Language Learning (private beta). It does not happen at Meta.SE.

Reproduced on Firefox, Google Chrome and Safari.

---

Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

---

Safari is a bit worse:

[image]

---

Comment: Happens on MSO also for me - http://i.stack.imgur.com/2ldH7.png

Comment: No repro on meta.superuser or meta.stackoverflow for me. WIndows 64 bit, Latest Firefox.

Comment: @DavidPostill that is strange because I can repro that on meta.so, both in Chrome and Firefox for [my profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) but you're right, yours shows fine for me ...

Comment: @rene Even stranger; I do see the bug in DavidPostill's profile page.

Comment: never mind, you can tell I'm not a good tester ...

Comment: As a note: you have to be on the Activity section of the profile for this bug to show up.

Comment: @wythagoras Weird, I see it in **rene's** profile, but **not** in mine.

Comment: I can see it on DavidPostill's, rene's and my own profile page. Win 10, Firefox (v45.0.1) and Chrome (v51.0.2700.0 dev-m).

Comment: @DavidPostill sure you view your meta profile? http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/users/80444/davidpostill?tab=topactivity - also, try to view it Incognito

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes. I see the issue with that link. and now with http://meta.superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill as well (which was **not** the case yesterday).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blame it on a bad merge.

Nick pushed a fix, live with you in the next build sometime later today.

Comment: Merge of users?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Code.